# KendoUI TreeView binding issue

Tags: kendo-ui

I am facing an issue , below code bind the tree for first time , but not working binding the tree on second time :(  but when i request third its bind again.

Means even request work .

please help me

Thanks in advance

Mobeen

// My Example Data

{"d":[{"_*type":"ManageUPPRM.UserDocumentDTO","DocumentID":1804105651,"DocumentName":"Google Talk","hasChildren":true},{"*_type":"ManageUPPRM.UserDocumentDTO","DocumentID":15854591701,"DocumentName":"desktop.ini","hasChildren":false},{"__type":"ManageUPPRM.UserDocumentDTO","DocumentID":15861429553,"DocumentName":"Jellyfish.jpg","hasChildren":false}]}

//Code

```
var datasource = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: function (options) {
                        var id = options.data.DocumentID;

                        if (typeof id == "undefined") {
                            id = "0"
                        }

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "../ManageUPWebService.asmx/GetAllDocuments",
                            dataType: "json",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            data: "{DocumentID:'" + id + "'}",
                            success: function (result) {
                                // notify the data source that the request succeeded
                                options.success(result.d);
                            },
                            error: function (result) {
                                // notify the data source that the request failed
                                options.error(result.d);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },
                schema: {
               model: {
                        id: "DocumentID",
                        text: "DocumentName",
                        hasChildren: "hasChildren"
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({

                checkboxes: {
                    checkChildren: true,
                    template: "<input type='checkbox' name='#=item.id#' data-text='#=item.DocumentName#' value='true' />"
                },

                loadOnDemand: true,
                dataSource: datasource,
                dataTextField: "DocumentName"
            });
```

Comment: Some time i see error in console Error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'set' of undefined

Comment: does the call is going to the server each time when you request for json data

Comment: Could you try to create JSFiddle/JSBin that reproduces it?

Comment: Thanks Rudresh for your  reply , yes call is going every time , and response is 200 ok

Comment: OnaBai thanks for your response , no i didn't try JSFiddle/JSBin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,
add a div with some id as the parent div of treeview

```
<div id="parent"><div id="treeview"></div></div>
```

and before binding the kendo tree

```
$("#treeview").remove();
$("<div id=\"treeview\" />").appendTo("#parent").kendoTreeView({
            checkboxes: {
                checkChildren: true,
                template: "<input type='checkbox' name='#=item.id#' data-text='#=item.DocumentName#' value='true' />"
            },

            loadOnDemand: true,
            dataSource: datasource,
            dataTextField: "DocumentName"
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Rudresh , binding working now , but now i am facing new issue , when i deselect the checkbox from button treeview not updating his state.

Comment: what state it is not updating? can you be more clear

Comment: if i programmatically change the checked checkbox to uncheck using jquery , its not updating the state of checkbox in treeview control.

Comment: Thanks Rudresh for your help , i have fixed that issue , by triggering the tree view change event.

Comment: Can you explain this , why we need parent dev.

Comment: because sometimes the data for the  old dropdown is present and events will not work thats why we will remove and recreate the dropdown